# Worksheet_Change multiple events

Tags: excel, vba

I'm pretty new to this topic Worksheet_Change. I wanted to put those 3 events together in one sheet.
 Could someone help me with this problem?
First and second one give me only date and user name in diffrent cells
second one blockes all cells after writing something in it. I  have already tried all...

Code 1:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rC As Range
If Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
For Each rC In Target.Cells
Range("F" & rC.Row) = Now()
Range("G" & rC.Row) = Environ("username")
Next rC
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Code 2:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim P2 As Range
If Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
For Each P2 In Target.Cells
Range("H" & P2.Row) = Now()
Range("I" & P2.Row) = Environ("username")
Next P2
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Code 3:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cel As Range
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Athens"
For Each cel In Target
If cel.Value <> "" Then
cel.Locked = True
End If
Next cel
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Athens"
End Sub
```

Comment: It's not that complicated. Just put each chunk of code after each other, and remove the Exit Subs, i.e. invert the logic of the If statements.

Comment: And modify the intersect if statements...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so?

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rC As Range
    Dim P2 As Range
    Dim cel As Range

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each rC In Target.Cells
            Range("F" & rC.Row) = Now()
            Range("G" & rC.Row) = Environ("username")
        Next rC
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each P2 In Target.Cells
            Range("H" & P2.Row) = Now()
            Range("I" & P2.Row) = Environ("username")
        Next P2
    Else
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Athens"
        For Each cel In Target
            If cel.Value <> "" Then
                cel.Locked = True
            End If
        Next cel
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Athens"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Target could be in multiple columns but your if is mutually exclusive...  Also Intersect may not be Nothing but that doesn't mean all cells in Target are in (eg) Col B.

Comment: I agree, probably a test should be added for the # of cells in Target.

Answer (score -1):

needed to change it to make it work as intended. I wanted to block all cells which were modified by direct interaction. Thanks for help! I couldn't do it without your help

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim rC As Range
 Dim P2 As Range
 Dim cel As Range


    Application.EnableEvents = True
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Athens"
    For Each cel In Target
        If cel.Value <> "" Then
            cel.Locked = True
            End If
    Next cel
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Athens"

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each rC In Target.Cells
        Range("F" & rC.Row) = Now()
        Range("G" & rC.Row) = Environ("username")
    Next rC
    Application.EnableEvents = True
ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each P2 In Target.Cells
        Range("H" & P2.Row) = Now()
        Range("I" & P2.Row) = Environ("username")
    Next P2
        Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
```

End Sub